# followings.json and followers.json shows blank screen

Tags: soundcloud

`followings.json` and `followers.json` shows a blank screen:

For example, [this link](http://api.soundcloud.com/users/kayfaraday/followings.json?client_id=879e9c59b2147c835bdd15a2265f1baf&limit=200).

Client id works, fine: I'm just curious about how to get the information showing again?

Answer (score 0):

According to the API documentation, all `/users` subresources take a user ID and not a user permalink. The behavior when using a permalink is undefined.

https://developer.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users